# Upgrade postgresql from 9.3 to 9.5 in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu-16.04, postgresql-9.3

I have Ubuntu 16.04 LTS installed in my machine with postgresql-9.3. (It looks I Keep this instance since 16.04 installs postgresql9.5).

Well, I installed 9.5 and remove 9.3 using...

```
sudo apt-get remove postgresql-9.3
```

Unfortunately I didn't know all databases and roles were in that instance (9.3) and are not shared with 9.5. when trying to log in with my users it doesn't work because they don't exist in that instance / cluster (am I right?)

I tried to install 9.3 using Ubuntu repository but it installs me just the 9.5. How can I move the all my roles and databases to 9.5 ??

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/pgupgrade.html ?

Comment: Do you still have your original 9.3 database around?  It sounds like you already deleted it when you used the remove command.  If that's the case you're going to have a tough time getting your data back.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To see if your database is still on your server check this folder :

```
ls /var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main/base/
```

If you have files there, this mean your database is still here !!
If nothing in this folder, this mean your life data have been deleted.

Did you made a regular backup of your database ?

If so, you need to install back your previous version of PostgreSQL and make a restore of it.

```
apt-get install postgresql-9.3
psql -h localhost
create database dbname;
psql -h localhost dbname < backup_file
```

After the normal process to upgrade on Debian or Ubuntu is this one :
service postgresql stop

On vire le clus­ter de la nouvelle version (norma­le­ment vide si on vient juste de l’ins­tal­ler : faire gaffe à ne pas lais­ser passer de temps entre l’ins­tal­la­tion de la nouvelle version et la migra­tion des données, pour que personne n’uti­lise le nouveau clus­ter)

Stop the new updated version of PostreSQL :

```
service postgresql stop
```

Drop the new updated version cluster to be sure nothing is inside :

```
pg_dropcluster --stop 9.5 main
```

Then data migration :

```
pg_upgradecluster -m upgrade 9.3 main
```

Then stop previous version of PotsgreSQL :

```
pg_dropcluster 9.3 main --stop
```

Remove the old version :

```
apt-get autoremove --purge postgresql-9.3
```

Then just restart PostgreSQL, the new version with database migrated :

```
service postgresql start
```

Hope this help.

But if you didn't do any backup, unfortunatly you should have loose everything.

Comment: when trying to install 9.3: "E: Package 'postgresql-9.3' has no installation candidate"

Comment: You need to refere the ubuntu version which contains this old version. Like this sudo apt-get install postgresql=9.3-1ubuntu1

Note that you may need to do some dependency resolution on your own in this case, but if there are any problems apt-get will tell you what is causing them. You'll need to do the following to get this to work:

sudo apt-get install postgresql=9.3-1ubuntu1 \
                     postgresql-common=9.3-1ubuntu1

Comment: A specific version of a package can be selected for installation by following the package name with an equals and the version of the package to select. This will cause that version to be located and selected for install. Alternatively a specific distribution can be selected by following the package name with a slash and the version of the distribution or the Archive name (stable, frozen, unstable).